# My css file is being cut (truncated) when using css-loader style-loader with webpack

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I just realized that my css file is being cut off when loading it through webpack. Is there a limit in the number of lines I can use for the file? My file has 683 lines but when I check the file in the browser is showing only 489 lines and the css after line 489 is not being applied.

This is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isProduction = env === 'production';

    return {
        entry: './src/app.js',
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        plugins: [new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from:'src/resources/assets',to:'images'} 
        ])],
        module: {
            rules: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader', 'css-loader'
                ]
            }]
        },
        devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
        }
    };
};
```